# Unable to compile app using apktool: "Asset package include not found"

Tags: java, android, compilation

I'm trying to compile an application but I'm having no luck.
I can't even compile an untouched app, i.e., if I decompile mms.apk (no errors at all) and I tried to compile right on, it doesn't work!
I have done this before when I still used windows 7 so idk why it isn't working.

One thing I noticed is that the frameworks get installed to `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\apktool\framework\1.apk`
is that okay? I'm using windows 8 now if that makes any difference.

anyway, here is the output I get:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

install the framework of your phone like this

```
apktool if framework-res.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

The file that is located at `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\apktool\framework\1.apk` could not be read properly.

It may be due to the fact that you didn't have permission to write the file initially during the `apktool if framework-res.apk` command. As you can see, during decompile apktool must load the frameworks so it can properly resolve resources during decompile. The first few lines of that error indicate apktool couldn't pull that file correctly.

I would do what Cristi said above, except make sure your in a admin launched command prompt window, so that you'll have permission to read/write to all portions of the C drive.

Comment: it installs the framework with no errors and decompiles just fine :/ I did what you told me and still doesn't work.. maybe because it's installing the framework in an odd location.. it should install to `C:\Users\John\apktool\framework\1.apk`, is it because I'm using windows 8 now? How can I solve it?

Comment: I test all builds on Win8 and Ubuntu prior to release. I don't experience that storage behavior. Are you logged in as an Admin account?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the updated version of APKTtool:

[Download APKTool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

Put all three files (*aapt.exe*, *apktool.jar* and *apktool.bat*) in one folder.

Then goto that folder directory using cmd and type `apktool d apkname.apk`.